# Script to Play/Pause Soundcloud tab with Apple Remote

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, soundcloud

I'm working on an AppleScript for my Apple Remote (via [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/)) that will Play/Pause playback on Soundcloud.

It's supposed to work similarly to the native Apple Remote <kbd>▶/❚❚</kbd> button for iTunes. On SoundCloud, `keystroke space` (<kbd>␣</kbd>) is *Play/Pause* playback;

- If no Soundcloud tab exists, open a Soundcloud tab and `keystroke space` (<kbd>▸</kbd>).
- If one Soundcloud tab exists, select it and `keystroke space` (will <kbd>‖</kbd> if already playing, or else <kbd>▸</kbd>).
- If multiple Soundcloud tabs exist, select the first one and `keystroke space` (Will either <kbd>‖</kbd> if the tab is playing, <kbd>▸</kbd> *that* tab if another tab is playing, or <kbd>▸</kbd> if no tab is playing).

So far I've been able to get it to open a new tab and start playing, or if one already exists select that tab – but it then doesn't play/pause – nor if an Soundcloud tab is already active.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://soundcloud.com" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                return
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
    open location "https://soundcloud.com/you/likes"
    activate
    delay 3
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke space
end tell
```

I'm an AppleScript newbie so unfortunately the best I can do is to experiment. Appreciative of any help.

Comment: The `return` ends the script. Change it to `exit repeat` and the script doesn't stop after finding a tab. The `open location` should be in the repeat loop. Otherwise it opens every time.

Comment: @user309603: Thanks, I tried this but tbh I didn't get the results you were pointing to. Maybe I was doing it wrong? If you're inclined, feel free to make an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script must exit the **loops**, and the script need an `if` condition, like this:

```
set soundcloudTab to false
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://soundcloud.com" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                set soundcloudTab to true
                exit repeat
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
        if soundcloudTab then exit repeat -- exit windows loop
    end repeat
    activate
    if not soundcloudTab then -- no Soundcloud tab exist
        open location "https://soundcloud.com/you/likes"
        delay 3
    end if
end tell
tell application "System Events" to keystroke space
```

---

Another solution is to use `JavaScript` to click on the **playPause** button (no need to activate the tab and "**Google Chrome**" doesn't need to be in the foreground):

```
set soundcloudTab to missing value
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        tell (first tab of w whose URL starts with "https://soundcloud.com") to if exists then
            set soundcloudTab to it
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    if soundcloudTab is missing value then
        open location "https://soundcloud.com/you/likes"
        delay 3
        set soundcloudTab to active tab of front window
    end if
    tell soundcloudTab to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('playControls__playPauseSkip')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click()"
end tell
```

Comment: Very neat JavaScript solution and now my Apple Remote can play Soundcloud :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above, I came up with a shorter, less brittle solution. Tough in my use case it assumes you already have exactly one Soundcloud tab open. Here's the main routine:

```
on controlSoundcloud(cmd)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat with theTab in every tab in every window
            if URL of theTab starts with "https://soundcloud.com" then
                execute theTab javascript "var el = document.querySelector('button.playControls__" & cmd & "'); el && el.click()"
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end controlSoundcloud
```

That by itself won't do anything. You still need to call it. Tack on one of these lines to the end of the script, depending on what you want to do.

```
-- play/pause
controlSoundcloud("play")
-- prev
controlSoundcloud("prev")
-- next
controlSoundcloud("next")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbling over this post also wants to control Soundcloud with their Apple Remote, here's how:

Assuming you already have [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/), you can add triggers to the *Apple Remote* tab for *Play/Pause*, *Next*, *Previous* track:

[image]

For Play, assign *Run Apple Script* as the *Predefined Action*. Copy/Paste *@jackjr300*'s `JavaScript` solution and hit Save.

For Next and Previous, paste the same JavaScript but just change `.getElementsByTagName('button')[1]` to:

- `.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]` for *Previous*
- `.getElementsByTagName('button')[2]` for *Next*.